Pyinstaller error - "'pyinstaller.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."
I have this tkinter code and I was trying to put it into an executable file, I have tried every method and I don't understand why, none of them work! This error in pyinstaller, how can I fix it?
"'pyinstaller.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.".

I use this command in my folder´s cmd:
pyinstaller.exe --onefile  main.py

and it gives me that error

This question is a duplicate, but I'm putting this answer here solely for visibility's sake.
Typically when you receive an error like this it's because the executable you're trying to run isn't on your computer's PATH environment variable. That is, Windows doesn't know where pyinstaller is, so it can't run it from the command line (NB: this is true for things other than pyinstaller as well!).
You can fix this by either using the complete path to the exe when you run the command, e.g.:
C:\wherever\you\installed\pyinstaller.exe --onefile  main.py

or (preferably) you can add pyinstaller to your PATH permanently by running this command:
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\wherever\you\installed\pyinstaller.exe

Be sure to enter this command carefully, as you can break things if you mess up.
Once you've done that, you should be able to run the pyinstaller.exe command like you'd expect.
If you prefer to use a GUI, you can open the Start menu and search for "Environment Variables", then click on "Edit System Environment Variables". There are plenty of tutorials/explainers online for "how to add something to PATH on Windows" (hint hint)
